# What is a person called before he is a patient

Tags: covid-19

I am working on COVID related app. There is a scenario when I need to collect details of person who wants to have COVID tests. I want to show a label on the app whose meaning is: Details of a person who wants to have COVID test.

So, I want to know the term for a person who wants to have COVID test. I searched through google but cannot find an appropritate word. So, I thought I should ask it here.

Please forgive me if this a very basic question, and please inform me if I missed some information in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Candidate.**

1 b: one likely or suited to undergo or be chosen for something specified
(e.g. a candidate for surgery).

<sup>[Merriam Webster.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have used Candidate word many a times, but cannot remember at this point. :D

Comment: @Vishal "Candidate" means they may not be selected. Is that a possibility with your app?

Comment: That user you were so generously trying to help (nails)? The belief has all the hallmarks of a (psychotic) delusion. Not judging *at all* (honestly). Just saying, no one can help the user to prove them correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an English word that means pre-patient. If you call a doctor's office and ask for an appointment, you become known to them as a patient the minute they type your name into the system. It doesn't matter that they haven't seen you, examined you, or run any tests yet; you're still a patient. That's what I would expect your app to do. Anything else would likely be confusing.

Source: Personal experience writing patient care reports and developing medical software.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I asked a group of people before asking this question here and got the same answer! But other answer suggests candidate. I think Candidate suits more to my use case, so I will go with that answer.